# how can i fire event to another class when something happen?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

```
class B
{
    int x =0;
    int loop=0;

    public void count()
    {
        while (loop=0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            x+=5`enter code here`;
            // fire event to another class 
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make event that fire when integer x is reach 15 to another class.

how can i fire event when my method reach number 15 to another class ?

Comment: Do you have a reference to an instance of the other class?

Comment: Use a `Timer` rather than trying to implement your own...incorrectly.

Comment: Since you've **clearly** never actually tried to compile or run this code, why not provide an example of something that demonstrates your problem? Who knows - while writing it you may actually learn something. Or - gasp - ask your teacher.

Comment: first you need to give the  `while` loop a proper condition opposed to an assignment statement.  Then add some functionality that allows the loops condition to become true or false.  Finally an `if` statement or a nested `while` statement... that calls your method if true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an event

```
public delegate void YourEvent(object sender, YourEventArgs e);
public event YourEvent YourHandler;
```

then when x reach 15 call

```
YourHandler(this, new YourEventArgs());
```

note YourEventArgs is just a class with whatever property you want to put in

On the class that will get the result just create a Handler for this instance, then that's it. Hope this helps.

```
B.YourHandler += new YourEvent(A_Handler);
```